# Curve calculate Y when X is known

Tags: location, find, curve, bezier, cubic

## The Question

Okay so basically what I'm trying to do, is calculating the Y location on a *Cubic Curve / Bezier Curve / Spline* when the X location is given.

I've searched everywhere on Stack Overflow and Google and I could find anything that actually worked!

## The Curve Points

```
x1 = 50d;
y1 = 400d / 2d + 100d;

x2 = 400d;
y2 = 400d / 2d + 100d;

x3 = 600d - 400d;
y3 = 400d / 2d - 100d;

x4 = 600d - 50d;
y4 = 400d / 2d - 100d;
```

*The reason that I calculate "600 - 400" and I don't just write "200" is because in my code "600" is actually the width of the window, which the Cubic Curve is rendered in. Thereby it actually says "width - 400" in my code.*

So the following code after, can calculate the X & Y on a Cubic Curve when T is given!

```
t = 0.5d;

cx = 3d * (x2 - x1);
cy = 3d * (y2 - y1);

bx = 3d * (x3 - x2) - cx;
by = 3d * (y3 - y2) - cy;

ax = x4 - x1 - cx - bx;
ay = y4 - y1 - cy - by;

point_x = ax * (t * t * t) + bx * (t * t) + cx * t + x1;
point_y = ay * (t * t * t) + by * (t * t) + cy * t + y1;
```

So again, what I'm trying to calculate is the Y location of a Curve when you know an X location. But the only thing that I'm able to calculate is both an X & Y location on the Curve when T is given.

*This is my first post, so if something isn't written 100% correctly, I apologize!*

Comment: What is the meaning of `T` given that the code sets it to 0.5? Is `Y` unique for any `X`? A formula such as `Y = square_root(X)` yields 2 values of `Y` for all X > 0 and no real values for X < 0.

Comment: you don't actually needs all the specific 'd' bits for this question; you're not giving code, so the fact that it's a double (or float, etc) doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cubic curve can have multiple 'y' values for an 'x' value, so you're going to have to perform root finding, after rotating the cubic curve so that it's aligned with the x/y axes. http://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#intersections covers this concept, but the idea is this:

1. take your curve, defined by points {p1,p2,p3,p4}, and take your line at x=X, defined by points {p5,p6} (where p5 is some coordinate (x,...) and p6 is another coordinate(x,...). The important part is that it's a vertical line, so both points have the same *x* value).
2. translate and rotate your cubic curve and your line, together, so that your line becomes horizontal, at new height *y* = 0.
3. you can now perform cubic root finding on the curve's *y* function. This may generate 0, 1, 2, or 3 distinct *t* values.
4. for each of these *t* values: in your normal, unrotated curve, compute the (x,y) coordinate given that *t* value. You will now have all the *y* values for a given *x* (all points will have the same *x* value, too).

In the article linked, have a look at the source for the cubic curve/line example, and to see how the rotation/rootfinding works, see the `BezierCurve align(Point start, Point end) {...` and `float[] findAllRoots(int derivative, float[] values) {...` functions. (especially note that after rotation, we're only finding the roots for the y-function! the x-function has become irrelevant for what we want to do)

Answer (score 0):

If your formulas are correct, theoretically one might use [Formula for cubic function roots](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#General_formula_for_roots) to express `t` dependency from `x`. Then from `x` you find `t`, from `t` you find `y`.